# executing a function on animation end breaks after first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

having trouble finding another way to show/hide div with reverse animation

if anyone knows another way or a better way of doing this i will be happy to hear

click on the bell a couple of times to see the bug

thanks in advance

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6wxqL38/2/)

```
$('#nav-bar-util').on('click', '.util-box', function() {
    $this = $(`${$(this).data('link')}`);

    if ($this.is(':hidden')) {
        $this
            .css('display', 'block')
            .removeClass('window-close')
            .addClass('window-active')
    } else {
        $this
            .removeClass('window-active')
            .addClass('window-close')
            .one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
                $this.css('display', 'none')
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using .toggleClass() instead of if-else statement.

The changes:

- the default class is added to the #notifications-nav in html
- 'display:block' property added to .window-active css class
- 'display none' property removed from #notifications-nav class

```js
$('#nav-bar-util').on('click', '.util-box', function() {
    $this = $(`${$(this).data('link')}`);
  $this.removeClass('hidden').toggleClass('window-close window-active');
});
```

```css
.util-box {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 50px;
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
transition: border-color 400ms;
}

@keyframes window-open {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}

@keyframes window-close {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
}

#notifications-nav,
#messages-nav,
#friend-requests-nav {
    background: #3e215c;
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.hidden {display:none}
#notifications-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.window-active {
    animation: window-open 250ms forwards;
    display:block;
}

.window-close {
    animation: window-close 250ms forwards;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex" id="nav-bar-util">

  <div class="util-box" data-link=#notifications-nav>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bell-o"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Class added -->
    <div id="notifications-nav" class="window-close hidden">
      You Don't have any notifications
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this one is that when the page loads the close animation triggers

Comment: its still broken, if you click a couple of times on the bell it still breaks after a couple of clicks

Comment: Try the code posted in my original reply. I believe you are trying to run the code I originally posted. (I deleted the link to the fiddle from the previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Working example of this problem

https://jsfiddle.net/n6wxqL38/5/

```
$('#nav-bar-util').on('click', '.util-box', function() {
    $this = $(`${$(this).data('link')}`);

    if (!$this.hasClass('is-active')) {
        $this.removeClass('is-close')
        $this.addClass('is-active')
    }
    else {
        $this.removeClass('is-active')
        $this.addClass('is-close')
    }
});
```